# I can't manage to render empty fields

Tags: theming, layout-builder

I have a custom template file for *List (text)* fields. I need to display these fields using the Layout builder module.

Everything works perfectly, until no value in those fields is selected. (The fields are just not displayed.)

What I actually need is rendering the fields even when they have no value.

I tried to use `hook_entity_display_build_alter()` and `hook_entity_view_alter()` to render the fields, but it already looks like too much hard-coding.

UPD.
This is what I'm trying to achieve (maybe it'll be easier to understand my goal)

[image: When List (text) field is empty]

When *List (text)* field is empty

[image: When List (text) field has selected option]

When *List (text)* field has selected option

Comment: I would create template overrides for the given fields, and add a conditional for when they are empty.

Comment: Do you mean adding condition in twig file? That's my main problem - twig templates for field is not rendered if field is empty (that's actually normal Drupal core behavior, but I'm trying to find a workaround for this thing). Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's the logic how Drupal renders fields by field items (and not by possible options). But shouldn't that be a radio element (single value field) and an extra entry <none>?

Comment: Have you tried the module https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_fields ? 
I never used it, but from the description it could cover your case